# Binding method returning retrofuture CompletableFuture

Tags: xamarin.android

Im binding Microsofts native android SDK for Azure Communication services so I can use it in my xamarin apps: https://github.com/Laerdal/Xamarin.AzureCommunicationCalling/tree/master/Bindings/Android

Its been working well, but in the latest version(https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.azure.android/azure-communication-calling/1.0.0-beta.8/aar) they started using java9.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture (retrofuture) instead of the "regular" CompletableFuture, and Im unable to make the binding lib work against this :(

When I add retrofuture and retrostream(dep from retrofuture) as an embedded jar, I get this error:

```
/Users/tompi/src/Xamarin.AzureCommunicationCalling/Bindings/Android/Xamarin.AzureCommunicationCalling.Android/obj/Debug/generated/src/Java9.Util.Concurrent.CompletableFuture.cs(11,107,11,153): error CS0738: 'CompletableFuture'   does not implement interface member 'ICompletionStage.RunAfterBoth(ICompletionStage, IRunnable)'. 'CompletableFuture.RunAfterBoth(ICompletionStage, IRunnable)' cannot implement 'ICompletionStage.RunAfterBoth(ICompletionStage,    IRunnable)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'ICompletionStage'.
```

I assume this is a binding problem with the retrofuture lib, appreciate it if anyone has any tips on how to fix it!

Comment: If anybody is still searching for a solution for this, I ended up making a tiny java library, to replace all retrofuture usage with regular futures, and then just binding this. Ugly hack, but works fine...

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing. Since I had no luck creating the Xamarin bindings directly for CommunicationServices, I created a java library. However, when I create the bindings for the java library, it gives me an error that the java reference type CommunicationTokenCredential is not found. I've added a reference jar for 'azure communication common'. But the error still persists. Any ideas? @tompi

Comment: I recommend using our nuget: https://github.com/Laerdal/Xamarin.AzureCommunicationCalling

Answer (score 1):

Which version of android-retrofuture and android-retrostreams are you using @tompi? We use 1.7.3 for both in the Calling SDK, fyi and the motivation to user the android-retrofuture backport rather than the official version is mainly due to the fact the ACS Calling SDK support Android SDK level 21.

Comment: Im using the same versions(in fact I use gradle to download all the correct deps...). This isnt really an issue with your library, its a problem with binding the retrofuture interface so I can use it with c#. I understand the reason you use it, although I dont agree :) It seems very marginal that API 21-23 devices will use ACS...

Answer (score 1):

Please try by adding below code in `Xamarin.AzureCommunicationCommon.Android.csproj`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedReferenceJar Include="Jars\android-retrofuture-1.7.3.jar" />
    <EmbeddedReferenceJar Include="Jars\android-retrostreams-1.7.3.jar" /
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I tried that, and I understand it would work if those libs were not exposed in the api. Problem is types from retrofuture are exposed in externally in ACS api, so we have to bind it, and the binding generator doesn’t work out of the box on it…

Comment: I agree. For my use calling I am dropping calling SDK .aar into a wrapper layer. so I do not need bindings for callings SDK.